# Why does the definite article appear in "the mid-40s"?

Tags: articles, definite-article, zero-article

Why is the definite article used before **mid-40s** and **30s** in this sentence from a [Washington Post weather report](http://www.washingtonpost.com/news/capital-weather-gang/wp/2018/03/15/d-c-area-forecast-gusty-winds-neutralize-todays-milder-air-another-chill-down-friday/)?

> Highs are mainly limited to **the mid-40s**, with wind chills in **the 30s** so bundle up.

I am confused because I don't see what is being specified and thus calls for the article, and also because the same site has other lines without the definite article. The following sentences contain a mix of usages with and without the article.

> The incoming surge of colder air pushes lows into **the mid- to upper 20s**, with **low 30s** limited to downtown.
>
> Winds finally begin to die down overnight under starry skies. Lows range from **mid-20s** to **low 30s**.
>
> Highs get up to **the more seasonable mid-50s**. Overnight is clear, with lows in **the upper 20s** to **mid-30s**.

Comment: `The` refers to a range of numbers, e.g. `the forties` include the set of nine numbers from 40 through 49. As to *why*, it is just `one` of `the many` peculiarities of English.

Answer (score 1):

The definite article is used there because **mid-40s** refers to a specific temperature range.